# What substring search algorithm is used by different JREs?

Tags: java, algorithm, string, substring

`java.lang.String` JavaDoc says nothing about the default `indexOf(String)` substring search algorithm. So my question is - which substring algorithms is used by different JREs?

Comment: May be this helps in understanding: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/lang/java/lang/String.java.htm

Comment: As Java is cross platform, there isn't much value in deviating from the reference open source code (except classes which deal with native code/platform dependant issues)

Comment: @Harry Joy, I see, default Sun (Oracle) JRE uses straightforward implementation with no trickery - just step-by-step comparation. What about JRockit and other?

Comment: may be they uses the same. I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @Harry Joy me too, and that's what the question about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what found for now:

### Oracle JDK 1.6/1.7, OpenJDK 6/7

```
static int indexOf(char[] source, int sourceOffset, int sourceCount,
                   char[] target, int targetOffset, int targetCount,
                   int fromIndex) {
if (fromIndex >= sourceCount) {
        return (targetCount == 0 ? sourceCount : -1);
}
    if (fromIndex < 0) {
        fromIndex = 0;
    }
if (targetCount == 0) {
    return fromIndex;
}

    char first  = target[targetOffset];
    int max = sourceOffset + (sourceCount - targetCount);

    for (int i = sourceOffset + fromIndex; i <= max; i++) {
        /* Look for first character. */
        if (source[i] != first) {
            while (++i <= max && source[i] != first);
        }

        /* Found first character, now look at the rest of v2 */
        if (i <= max) {
            int j = i + 1;
            int end = j + targetCount - 1;
            for (int k = targetOffset + 1; j < end && source[j] ==
                     target[k]; j++, k++);

            if (j == end) {
                /* Found whole string. */
                return i - sourceOffset;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

### IBM JDK 5.0

```
public int indexOf(String subString, int start) {
    if (start < 0) start = 0;
    int subCount = subString.count;
    if (subCount > 0) {
        if (subCount + start > count) return -1;
        char[] target = subString.value;
        int subOffset = subString.offset;
        char firstChar = target[subOffset];
        int end = subOffset + subCount;
        while (true) {
            int i = indexOf(firstChar, start);
            if (i == -1 || subCount + i > count) return -1; // handles subCount > count || start >= count
            int o1 = offset + i, o2 = subOffset;
            while (++o2 < end && value[++o1] == target[o2]);
            if (o2 == end) return i;
            start = i + 1;
        }
    } else return start < count ? start : count;
}
```

### Sabre SDK

```
  public int indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)
  {
    if (fromIndex < 0)
      fromIndex = 0;
    int limit = count - str.count;
    for ( ; fromIndex <= limit; fromIndex++)
      if (regionMatches(fromIndex, str, 0, str.count))
        return fromIndex;
    return -1;
  }
```

Feel free to update this post.

Answer (score 1):

There's src.zip in JDK which shows implementation:

```
/**
 * Code shared by String and StringBuffer to do searches. The
 * source is the character array being searched, and the target
 * is the string being searched for.
 *
 * @param   source       the characters being searched.
 * @param   sourceOffset offset of the source string.
 * @param   sourceCount  count of the source string.
 * @param   target       the characters being searched for.
 * @param   targetOffset offset of the target string.
 * @param   targetCount  count of the target string.
 * @param   fromIndex    the index to begin searching from.
 */
static int indexOf(char[] source, int sourceOffset, int sourceCount,
                   char[] target, int targetOffset, int targetCount,
                   int fromIndex) {
if (fromIndex >= sourceCount) {
        return (targetCount == 0 ? sourceCount : -1);
}
    if (fromIndex < 0) {
        fromIndex = 0;
    }
if (targetCount == 0) {
    return fromIndex;
}

    char first  = target[targetOffset];
    int max = sourceOffset + (sourceCount - targetCount);

    for (int i = sourceOffset + fromIndex; i <= max; i++) {
        /* Look for first character. */
        if (source[i] != first) {
            while (++i <= max && source[i] != first);
        }

        /* Found first character, now look at the rest of v2 */
        if (i <= max) {
            int j = i + 1;
            int end = j + targetCount - 1;
            for (int k = targetOffset + 1; j < end && source[j] ==
                     target[k]; j++, k++);

            if (j == end) {
                /* Found whole string. */
                return i - sourceOffset;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: And what about other JREs (I mean, non-standard)?

Comment: @Frozen Spider I don't know :) But since there's no limitations mentioned in JavaDoc or JLS, it could be anything reasonable.

Comment: That's why I'm asking the question :) I myself have Sun's JDK, so I'm wondering about other implementations.

Answer (score 1):

fwiw (in case this Q is about the performance of different algorithms) on appropriate hardware and with a sufficiently recent oracle jvm (6u21 and later as detailed in the [bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6875866)), `String.indexOf` is implemented via the relevant SSE 4.2 intrinsics.. see chapter 2.3 in this [intel reference doc](http://software.intel.com/file/18187/)

Answer (score 0):

As most of the time indexOf is used for small substrings in reasonable small strings it is I believe save to assume that a fairly straight forward algorithm like the one shown by Victor is used. There are more advanced algorithms that work better for large strings but AFAIK these all perform worse for relative short strings.

Comment: @Frozen: to know for certain, you'd have to look at the API source for each JVM's runtime library. There is no mandated standard string search algorithm for the JVM.

Comment: Well, I'll do that if I'll get no sufficient answer.

Comment: @Frozen Spider: If it is really that important to you to know the exact implementation details you shouldn't ask. You should go check for yourself because relying on the accuracy of the answers would be foolish. Also keep in mind that the implementation can change from version to version.